# Generating additional rows based on a condition within the same data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame like DF below which will be imported directly from the database (as tibble).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


date_until <- dmy("31.05.2019")
date_val  <- dmy("30.06.2018")

DF <-  data.frame( date_bal   = as.Date(c("2018-04-30", "2018-05-31", "2018-06-30", "2018-05-31", "2018-06-30")),
                   department = c("A","A","A","B","B"),
                   amount     = c(10,20,30,40,50)
)

DF <- DF %>%
  as_tibble()
DF
```

It represents the amount of money spent by each department in a specific month. My task is to project how much money will be spent by each department in the following months until a specified date in the future (in this case date_until=31.05.2019)

I would like to use tidyverse in order to generate additional rows for each department where the first column date_bal would be a sequence of dates from the last one from "original" DF up until date_until which is predefined. Then I would like to add additional column called "DIFF" which would represent the difference between DATE_BAL and DATE_VAL, where DATE_VAL is also predefined. My final result would look like this:
[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9hu0.jpg)

I have managed to do this in the following way:

1. first filter data from DF for department A
2. Create another DF2 by populating it with date sequence from min(dat_bal) to date_until from 1.
3. Merge data frames from 1. and 2. and then add calculated columns using mutate

Since I will have to repeat this procedure for many departments I wonder if it's possible to add rows (create date sequence) in existing DF (without creating a second DF and then merging).

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add one day to the dates, create a sequence and then rollback to the last day of the previous month.

```
seq(min(date_val + days(1)), date_until + days(1), by = 'months')[-1] %>% 
  rollback() %>% 
  tibble(date_bal = .) %>% 
  crossing(DF %>% distinct(department)) %>% 
  bind_rows(DF %>% select(date_bal, department)) %>% 
  left_join(DF) %>% 
  arrange(department, date_bal) %>% 
  mutate(
    amount = if_else(is.na(amount), 0, amount),
    DIFF = interval(
      rollback(date_val, roll_to_first = TRUE), 
      rollback(date_bal, roll_to_first = TRUE)) %/% months(1)
  )
```

Comment: That's really nice. I assume you add a day to the date sequence and then roll back to avoid issues with February?

Comment: Correct. But not only February causes problems. If you add a month to "30.04.2019" it won't give you the last day of May.

Comment: Thanks! :) This idea is similar to my solution (with your code being much more neater and elegant than mine). However, I wonder if there is a possibility to do that without using left_join (I tried several options using complete() or pad(), unfortunately without success). Also, in this case a row for department B is generated where date_bal=30.04.2018 whereas the first date_bal for B department should be 31.05.2018.

Comment: I edited my code. The issue with 31.05.2018 for department B is resolved. In addition, I created the DIFF column and substituted NAs in the amount column. I would stick to the `left_join`.

Comment: This is by far the best solution I have. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.